# oop cant get this small script to work properly logging in

Tags: php, oop

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm new and just learning.

login.php

```
<?php

    include 'core/init.php';

    if   (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user = new User();

        if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
            echo 'you need to enter a username and password';
        } else if ($user->userExists($username) === false) {
            echo 'we cant find that username. have you registered?';
        } else echo 'ok';
     }

    ?>      <?php

    include 'core/init.php';

    if   (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user = new User();

        if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
            echo 'you need to enter a username and password';
        } else if ($user->userExists($username) === false) {
            echo 'we cant find that username. have you registered?';
        } else echo 'ok';
     }

    ?>      <?php

    include 'core/init.php';

    if   (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user = new User();

        if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
            echo 'you need to enter a username and password';
        } else if ($user->userExists($username) === false) {
            echo 'we cant find that username. have you registered?';
        } else echo 'ok';
    }

?>
```

User.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/classes/Connect.php';

    class User {

        private $db;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->db = new Connect();
            $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
        }

        public function userExists($username) {
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $username);
            $st->execute();

            if ($st->rowCount() == 1) {
                return true;
            } else return false;    
        }    
    }
?>
```

Ive been tring to learn OOP and everyone tells me the best way to learn is to try rather than ask for help. I'm tring to build a simple login and then make it more complex.

When I enter the correct username it doesn't `echo` ok. Instead, it `echo`s we can't find that username. Have you registered? Any help please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your `Connect`-class (and especially the method `rowCount`) works, but the problem seems to be the following: Your query returns the number of user_ids with the given username but you count rows.

Replacing

```
$st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username=?");
```

with

```
$st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=?");
```

should do the trick.

And since you are learning some more comments:

`empty($username) === true` is equal to `empty($username)`. Most programmers prefer the latter  (since its shorter).

Also it seems to make more sense to declare the method `userExists` as static.

Comment: thanks i am just learning but with help on here i will learn faster and better thanks again

Comment: Re: comparing with `true` or `false`, I would say the latter is preferred when the return value of the method/function is a boolean value.  It is redundant to compare a boolean to another boolean.